# Gnome terminal 3.22 not starting

Tags: gnome, archlinux, gnome-terminal

I just updated my arch linux to gnome 3.22 and it broke many things.
Most annoying is that gnome-terminal won't start.
I checked journalctl and found that :

```
oct. 18 15:11:05 jarvis dbus-daemon[727]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
oct. 18 15:11:05 jarvis systemd[711]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis org.gnome.Shell.desktop[745]: Window manager warning: Could not import pending buffer, ignoring commit: Failed to create texture 2d due to size/format constraints
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis gnome-terminal-[1569]: Error flushing display: Broken pipe
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis kernel: traps: gnome-terminal-[1569] trap int3 ip:7f21f3389ff1 sp:7ffd9c3e2bb0 error:0
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 1592/UID 0).
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis systemd[711]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=5/TRAP
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis systemd[711]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis systemd[711]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
oct. 18 15:11:06 jarvis systemd-coredump[1593]: Process 1569 (gnome-terminal-) of user 1000 dumped core.

            Stack trace of thread 1569:
            #0  0x00007f21f3389ff1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
            #1  0x00007f21f338c731 g_log_writer_default (libglib-2.0.so.0)
            #2  0x00007f21f338ab8c g_log_structured_array (libglib-2.0.so.0)
    ...
```

Going on and on on different libc.so.6 calls.

I can't find how to fix this.
Does any one have an idea of what happened ? and of what I should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switch login screen to use `Xorg`,

edit file: `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and uncomment `WaylandEnable=false`:

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
# WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: Yep, turns out my gnome had automatically switched to Wayland. I don't know about that config line but changing back to Xorg in login screen fixed my issues. It's bad though. Would have been nice if everything worked in Wayland.